# How can I make an image fill a specific container but not its parent container in Next.js + Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a Next.js project with Tailwind CSS and I have a specific requirement regarding image positioning and sizing within a parent container.

I have a structure where I have three images: background.png, frame.png, and hero_image.png. The background.png image is larger and acts as a background, while the frame.png is placed on top of it, and I want hero_image.png to fill only the frame.png and not its parent container.

Here's my current code:

```
<div className='relative flex px-10 justify-center'>
  <!-- Other image elements -->

  <div className="relative">
    <Image className='z-20 w-72 lg:w-max' src={"/Home/background.png"} width={506} height={660} alt='blog' />
    <Image className='absolute inset-0 z-20 w-56 lg:w-max m-auto' src={"/Home/frame.png"} width={400} height={400} alt='blog' />
    <div className='absolute inset-0 z-20'>
      <Image className='object-cover w-full h-full rounded-full' src={"/Home/hero_image.png"} width={500} height={500} alt='blog' />
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Other image elements -->
</div>
```

How can I modify my code to make hero_image.png fill only the frame.png while keeping background.png as a background?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this effect using Next.js and Tailwind CSS. Thank you!

I've tried using the object-cover class and other positioning classes from Tailwind CSS, but hero_image.png keeps filling the entire parent container (background.png) instead of just the frame.png.

Comment: Have you tried add object-cover w-full h-full to your image ? If that does not work maybe add a relative class to the parent div maybe ?